# Tweetbot like shrink view transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, transition

Does anyone know how to achieve the present view controller's view to shrink and put another one over it with a transparency? It is achieved in Tweetbot 3 when you tap on your avatar in the top left on the navigation bar. Should I take a snapshot for example?

[image: The Tweetbot transition I mean]

Comment: What tool are you using for the gif anim please?

Comment: you can try to “combine” the two: https://github.com/autresphere/ASDepthModal with https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/namodalsheet or https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mzformsheetcontroller

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve this effect you will have to rebuild your view stack from scratch.

So as there is no possibility to change the `viewController.view`'s frame, you'll have to add a kind of container subview a little like this:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize container;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:container];
    // add all views later to this insted of self.view

    // continue viewDidLoad setup
}
```

Now if you have that, you can animate the shrinking behavior like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        container.frame = CGRectMake(10, 17, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-34);
    }];
```

Okay, I assume you are developing for iOS 7, so we'll make use of some new APIs here (for earlier versions there are alternative frameworks). Now since WWDC `UIView`'s got a `resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:(CGRect) afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL) withCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)` method returning a single `UIView` object.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        container.frame = CGRectMake(10, 17, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-34);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UIView *viewToBlur = [self.view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:container.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];   
    }];
```

If you do not want to rewrite your view management, you can also first take a snapshot of your main view this way, set it to the container and then animate only the image. But remember, you can not interact with the captured view then.

When you've got that, you can download the two category files from [this](https://github.com/iGriever/TWSReleaseNotesView/tree/master/TWSReleaseNotesView) repo (They're from WWDC, so directly from Apple!). Basically, what they do is, they add some cool new methods to the `UIView` class, of which we'll use `applyDarkEffect`. I haven't tested this, maybe another method fits your needs better here.

Anyways if we implement that into the block and maybe also add a `UIImageView` to display the blurred overlay, it should look something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        container.frame = CGRectMake(10, 17, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-34);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UIView *viewToBlur = [self.view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:container.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        UIImage *image = [viewToBlur applyDarkEffect];
        UIImageView *blurredView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [self.view addSubview:blurredView];

        // optionally also animate this, to achieve an even smoother effect
        [blurredView setImage:image];

    }];
```

You can then add your `SecondViewController`'s view on top of the stack, so that it's delegate methods will still be called. The bounce effect of the incoming account view can be achieved via the new UIView animation method `animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) delay:(NSTimeInterval) usingSpringWithDamping:(CGFloat) initialSpringVelocity:(CGFloat) options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion` (more on that in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_36))

I hope that will help you with your project.

Comment: I highly doubt that they are changing the frame to make the view shrink. A scale transform seems much more likely.

Comment: There's a bunch of different ways to animate it, but you have to insert the container View

Comment: I will try it out, but can you tell me how I call `SecondViewController` so I still can se the `blurredView` we just created? I suppose setting `[UIColor clearColor]` as it's backgroundColor doesn't cut it.

Comment: If you allocinit a new instance of your SecondController and then add it's view with a transparent Background color to the FirstController the Blurred image will be behind the SecondController. You can then set it up in the viewDidLoad

Comment: You could do something with Quartz and the .layer of the view.. I'll try something tonight